# C code with callback called from Java JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have C code that has a init method. In this method, I register some callbacks:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_a_b_D_connect(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
bool success &= txRegisterConnectionStateChangedHandler(hContext, &hConnectionStateChangedTicket, OnEngineConnectionStateChanged, NULL) == TX_RESULT_OK;
return success;
}
```

The callback function is also defined in the C code:

```
void TX_CALLCONVENTION OnEngineConnectionStateChanged(TX_CONNECTIONSTATE connectionState, TX_USERPARAM userParam)
{
// ... various case statements
}
```

From my Java code, I call the C connect method. This works fine, but the problem is, I don't get all the callback, since my Java code terminates, as soon as all Java statements are executed.

How can I change this behaviour? I want to run the C code ifinetly until I terminate it.

Comment: Your C code needs to either block execution until it is done, or you need to devise a way to wait for it to complete.

Comment: You could check out [JavaCPP - Creating Callbacks Functions](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp#creating-callback-functions) for that. It would save you a lot of trouble.